# How to use Formik with input names that have dots "."?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm unable to get `handleChange` to update an input with dots "." in the name. Has anyone solved this?

```
<Formik component={({
  handleSubmit,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  values,
  errors,
}) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      value={values['name.of.input']}
      name="name.of.input"
    />
    {errors['name.of.input'] && <div>{errors['name.of.input']}</div>}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
)} />;
```

---

### Edit: Here is the refactored version that works

```
<Formik component={({
  initialValues={{
    name: {
      of: { 
        input: ''
      }
    }
  }},
  handleSubmit,
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  values,
  errors,
}) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      value={values.name.of.input}
      name="name.of.input"
    />
    {getIn(errors, 'name.of.input') && <div>getIn(errors, 'name.of.input')</div>}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
)} />;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `getIn`  and you can see an examples in the docs [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/connect) and [here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray#fieldarray-validation-gotchas).

```
const inputValue = getIn(values, 'name.of.input')
const inputError = getIn(errors, 'name.of.input')
const inputTouched = getIn(touched, 'name.of.input')
```

Comment: This works nice replacing value with value={getIn(values, 'name.of.input')}. The one draw back is I get uncontrolled input warnings, but I don't see away around that

Comment: @JeremiahMuela if you are getting uncontrolled input warnings, it isn't because of `getIn`, it's because in `values` there is no `name.of.input` and `getIn` is returning undefined. The problem is probably on your `initialValues` or on how you set the values of the component

Answer (score 2):

`name.of.input` means your Formik state should have shape something like this:

```
{
  name: {
    of: {
      input: ''
    }
  }
}
```

Now the values you're getting from Formik will also have the same shape, so to access value off of values you need do this:
`values={values.name.of.input}`

Comment: Oh yea! Thanks. I need to use _.get() so I don't get null errors, but this got me going. The one draw back is I get uncontrolled input warnings, but I don't see away around that.